# get current directory of symlink'd php script and not actual php script

Tags: php, directory, symlink

I have a script that is symlinked from one folder to another

```
/var/www/default/index.php
```

which is symlinked to

```
/var/www/mysite/index.php
```

However when i call **DIR** from mysite the path resolves to the origial path under default. How do i make it return the mysite path (the symlinked folder, not the actual folder)

Comment: You might `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see if any of the path variables contain the path you are needing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For Web Server requests**

dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) will give you what you need.

Failing that $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or even REQUEST_URI may have what you need, depending on your server configuration.

**For CLI (command Line)**

this won't work in cli (command line) scripts as $_SERVER is added by the web server.

Fortunately it's a lot easier with cli scripts (as there is no web server to mess about with things).

All you need is to read the command line that started the script: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php. The first argument $argv[0] is always the name that was used to run the script.

Comment: Thanks robbie for your suggestion. Using what you said I came up with this which worked for both web and cli.

    define('ROOT', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));

Comment: Nice solution, Robbie. Could you please fix the typo in _dir_name_ (should be _dirname_)

Comment: Of course not - $_SERVER is added by the web server. Fortunately it's a lot easier with CLI scripts as the web server doesn't mess up the path. All you need is to read the command line that started the script: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php. I'll add to answer.

Comment: Readers, beware! The "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or even REQUEST_URI will have it." part is entirely incorrect. They are ***URL paths***, which have ***nothing to do with the actual filesystem (dir) path*** of the script. They may accidentally have some matching parts, but that's all. E.g. a quick test here for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains `/prj/tag-test/prop-autotest/`, while the actual dir is: `/srv/szabi/prj/ALL/devtools/test/prop-autotest`, as per the web server configuration...

Comment: @sz - thanks for the comment - it was add as an alternative option for those situations where the first option didn't work, and you need a fall back. I've added the word "may" and clarified it depends on server config.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the **current path** with symlink you can ask your host OS:

`$path = exec('pwd');`

Answer (score 1):

May be useful:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['PWD']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the full unresolved system path of a cli script, SCRIPT_PATH will be insufficient.

```
php -f symlink/script.php
```

**SCRIPT_FILENAME** will contain **symlink/script.php**

I have created a php/gist that [gets the unresolved path to the php file.](https://gist.github.com/projectivemotion/c3ca6c7c2ec2022ec547a415618dfb1c)

Here is the outcome of the function:

```
 $ php -f subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink/app.php
 PWD: /tmp/phpcode                                                                           
 SCRIPT_FILENAME: subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink/app.php                 
___FILE__ : /tmp/phpcode/app.php                                                             
 getSymlink(): /tmp/phpcode/subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink/subdir/mysymlink
```