# Have script path with unresolved symlinks in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, path, symlink

Let's say we have a web directory with the following paths:

```
framework/
    index.php
    ...
instance/
    index.php -> ../framework/index.php (symlink)
    ...
```

If we now make a request for `(...)/instance/index.php` PHP will resolve the symlinks and set `__FILE__` as `(...)/framework/index.php`

Is there a way around this so e.g. `dirname(__FILE__)` would be `(...)/instance`?

**EDIT:** Since it has been pointed out, I'm actually not sure if PHP itself is resolving the links or something else. In my case I'm using `nginx` as a webserver with `php-fpm` as FastCGI.

*(The background is that I want to have multiple instances of a CMS or Framework referencing a common code base.)*

Comment: Are you sure PHP is doing this and not the webserver?

Comment: No. I just guessed from the php manual: `__FILE__ The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved.` Could be this is not done by php itself though.

Comment: This solve my problem [dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525880/get-current-directory-of-symlinkd-php-script-and-not-actual-php-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approximation for your case is `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` to get the "instance" dir, if you can live with the general warning in the doc about the `$_SERVER` vars:

> There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these;
>   servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

Also, the PHP manual [does not explicitly promise](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) that symlinks will be preserved, but that seems to be the case (unless of course your server thinks otherwise). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304606/1479945).

(Note: this also works in CLI mode. If the script was launched via a relative path (to the CWD), PHP will keep it that way, so you may end up with "." then.)

**However, for the general problem** (of getting *any* script's dir with symlinks preserved), this doesn't work. It only works for the script that has been reached via HTTP. Since any other scripts you `include` later on will all have the same `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` (of course), regardless of their location, `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` will yield the wrong dir if they are located elsewhere...

I don't think PHP has a solution for that today (as of v7.2).

*(And you were correct initially: PHP is doing the symlink-resolving for `__FILE__`, irrespective of your server. And it's unlikely that this [would ever change](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37603), because it has stayed this way for too long (and too much code depends on it), even though there's `realpath()` if we wanted the resolved path, while there's no bullet-proof solution for the symlinked case.)*